# Nginx + php-fpm: почему file not found? почему No input file specified?

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, fastcgi

Здравствуйте.
Установил на один хост nginx, на второй - php-fpm. Хочу добиться исполнения php на втором.

В интернете много где рекомендуют установить значение параметра **cgi.fix_pathinfo=0** в файле php.ini. Если я это делаю, то при запросе страницы XXXXX.com/index.php получаю страницу с текстом **No input file specified**, а в лог пишется:

**"[error] 31572#31572: *1 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Unable to open primary script: /var/www/XXXXX.com/html/index.php (No such file or directory)" while reading response header from upstream, client: XXX.XXX.X.XX, server: XXXXX.com, request: "GET /index.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://XXX.XXX.XXX.XX:9000", host: XXXXX.com ".**

Если же я устанавливаю значение этого параметра **cgi.fix_pathinfo=1**, то при запросе страницы XXXXX.com/index.php получаю сообщение **file not found**.

Печаль в том, что я уже сутки не могу понять как лечить ни первое, ни второе. Надеюсь, кто-нибудь подскажет в чем ошибка.

Код сервера привожу ниже:

```
server {

  listen 443;
  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/XXXXX.com.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/XXXXX.com.key; 
  root /var/www/XXXXX.com/html;
  index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
  server_name XXXXX.com www.XXXXX.com;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ { 
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param REQUEST_METHOD $request_method;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name; 
    fastcgi_pass XXX.XXX.XXX.XX:9000; #ip второго хоста(на котором php установлен)

    fastcgi_read_timeout 300; 
  } 

  location ~ /\.ht { 
    deny all; 
  }
}

server {

  listen 80 default_server;
  listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
  server_name XXXXX.com www.XXXXX.com;
  return 301 https://XXXXX.com;

}
```

Comment: На втором хосте PHP-файлы присутствуют?

Comment: На второй хост я только установил php и прописал прослушивание 9000 порта. Разве второй хост не должен искать этот файл на первом хосте?

Comment: лол нет, никакой передачи файлов между хостами не предполагается

Comment: Передачи не предполагается, но насколько я понял все файлы все равно должны быть на первом хосте(где nginx) и второй хост(где php) должен их исполнять даже если они не на нем. Вы уверены что я не прав?

Comment: да, вы не правы. на втором хосте у вас запущен интерпретатор php. он получает **информацию, содержащую путь и имя файла**, который следует интерпретировать. пытается файл прочитать — а его-то и нет на диске.

Comment: @FirstNameLastName каким образом второй хост их исполнит без передачи? Да, я не то что уверен, я точно знаю, что это так.

Comment: Видимо, в заблуждение меня ввело то, что большинство примеров в сети относятся к случаям, когда и nginx и интерпретатор установлены на одном хосте. Большое спасибо за ответы, очень помогли!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Интерпретатор PHP видит файлы только на том хосте, на котором находится. Если он выполняется на втором хосте, а файла нет - то и выполнить этот файл он не сможет.

Nginx не делает *никакой магии*. Всё, что делает nginx - передаёт запросы дальше по цепочке, которую вы определяете. Он не пытается и не будет пытаться получить файл кодом PHP с локального диска и отправить куда-то там ещё для выполнения.

Вы можете научить PHP видеть файлы на других хостах, если подключите каталоги с файлами [по NFS](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_File_System) или ещё как. Тогда для PHP файлы будут как локальный, хотя на самом деле они будут на диске на другом сервере. Уверен что вам такие сложности не нужны.